# How to define ‘impossible’ using propositional modal logic?

Tags: modal-logic, propositional-logic

I am trying to define impossibility using the symbols we have in propositional modal logic. I got ‘negation diamond alpha’ in mind as equivalent to ‘it is impossible that alpha’. It that correct and is there other ways to define it?

Comment: Yes; [impossible](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/#ModLog) is "not-possible"

Comment: Cool! Thanks. Any chance you can provide with another definition?

Comment: Use the def of possible form necessary: Pos = not Nec not.

Comment: You could also express it as "necessarily ~alpha", which is equivalent to "~possibly alpha", just take the second of the two equalities given in the opening of [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_logic) and substitute ~alpha in for P (and note that when you do this for ~P you get ~~alpha which is equivalent to alpha).